# Certbot SSL keys file names

Tags: ssl, mqtt, lets-encrypt

I am setting up SSL for an IOT device that uses MQTT protocol acting as a client and connecting to a broker server.  The server is using Certbot for SSL keys and registration.  I configure the IOT device using AT commands and in the AT command I need the **cacert, clientcert, and clientkey** shown in the picture below.  But I am wondering what are the names of these files on my server which is Ubuntu 20?

My best guess is one of the files below:

```
root@broker1:/etc/letsencrypt/keys# ls
0000_key-certbot.pem  0001_key-certbot.pem  0002_key-certbot.pem  0003_key-certbot.pem
```

or

```
root@broker1:/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydnsaddress# ls
README  cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem
```

[image: manual excerpt]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using SSL Client authentication the only files you need on the client will be `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<hostanme>/fullchain.pem`

If you are using SSL Client authentication then you will need a certificate and private key specific to that client and that will not be issued by LetsEncrypt but by a private CA.

Comment: Okay does fullchain.pem correspond to cacert?  Or is it clientcert or clientkey?

Comment: it should be used as the cacert